# How can I create a smooth blink-fading between two colors?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to get my icon blinking smoothly from the original color to my indicator color and back to the original one to show that there is something in progress. How can I do this?

```css
.fa-cloud {
  color: #666666;
}

.fa-cloud.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud active"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an css animation on your active class, like this:

```
.fa-cloud {
  color: #666666;
}

.fa-cloud.active {
        animation: blink 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0%{color: #666666;}
    50%{color: blue;}
    100%{color: #666666;}
}
```

that would make the cloud blink between the grey and the blue color as long as it has the classes fa-cloud and active